# Azerothcore - Docker .env MySQL-Password not working

Tags: docker, azerothcore

This was orginally asked via this github issue:
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/3527

When copying the `./.env.dist` file to `./.env` and changing the password for the mysql database the password is still set to "password" after the containers are up and running.

Per the docker install guide here:
https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker

Doing this should change the mysql database password.

I have tried the following:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker system prune
```

but still no luck. I've tried it with an older version of the repo from my backup and there it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a persistent volume for the ac-database docker. here is what I would try:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose down
docker system prune
docker system prune --volumes
```